# How to remove a role from specific user

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I wanna remove a role from specific user, cannot seem to get it working (im using Discord.js v13)

```
var role4 = msg.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name == "Role Name")

client.users.fetch("321257540442652672").roles.remove(role4)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1)** Users don't have roles, GuildMembers do. You have to get the GuildMember object

**2)** `.fetch()` returns a promise, you must handle it.

**3)** Ensure you receive a valid role object.

```js
var role4 = msg.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name == "Role Name");
if (!role4) return console.error("No role found");

msg.guild.members.fetch("321257540442652672")
   .then(member => {
      member.roles.remove(role4);
   })
   .catch(_ => console.log("No member found");
```